# Journey Builder first wait takes too long

Tags: journeybuilder, wait-element

I have a JB set up, it's quite straightforward. Just a few sends after a few wait periods. 
I need the first wait to be 1 minute (I need so I can do a client walkthrough/demostration).
But sometimes (not always, just sometimes) this first wait can take like 20 or 30 minutes; which is problematic if you are on a live demostration!

Does anyone know a reason for this?

Comment: Which entry source are you using for your journey? The problem may be due to the synchronization gap when using synchronized data sources.

Comment: Please also check the event results (accepted contacts) to know exactly when which activity happened. If the contact has been injected with the delay and the wait activity works correctly (which I assume is the case), then it is a problem with the sync gap and means you need to change the way the journey is triggered.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Markus for your feedback. I was actually not interpreting correctly what was happening. Entries seemed to be stuck in the first wait, because the journey tooltip shows no population in the fisrt send. But the entries were actually enqueued in the triggered send, and not in the wait activity.